# DVR whose residue field has characteristic $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could you give me an example of DVR whose residue field has characteristic $0$?

I came up with the following, but I don't have confidence.

> Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve, the local ring at $P∈C$, $K[C]p$ is
> DVR whose residue field is $K$. So, the case $chK＝0$ are examples.

Comment: What about K[[X]], the ring of formal power series over a field?

Comment: Take $K=\Bbb{C}$ and the simplest example of smooth curve you know. What do you get for $K[C]$ and $K[C]_p$?